# Combinations of features using Python NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, combinations, feature-extraction

For an assignment I have to use different combinations of features belonging to some data, to evaluate a classification system. By features I mean measurements, e.g. height, weight, age, income. So for instance I want to see how well a classifier performs when given just the height and weight to work with, and then the height and age say. I not only want to be able to test what two features work best together, but also what 3 features work best together and would like to be able to generalise this to ***n*** features.

I've been attempting this using numpy's mgrid, to create n dimensional arrays, flattening them, and then making arrays that use the same elements from each array to create new ones. Tricky to explain so here is some code and psuedo code:

```
import numpy as np

def test_feature_combos(data, combinations):
    dimensions = combinations.shape[0]
    grid = np.empty(dimensions)
    for i in xrange(dimensions):
        grid[i] = combinations[i].flatten() 
    #The above code throws an error "setting an array element with a sequence" error which I understand, but this shows my approach.

    **Pseudo code begin**
    For each element of each element of this new array, 
    create a new array like so:
    [[1,1,2,2],[1,2,1,2]] --->  [[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]]
    Call this new array combo_indices
    Then choose the columns (features) from the data in a loop using:
    new_data = data[:, combo_indices[j]]

combinations = np.mgrid[1:5,1:5]
test_feature_combos(data, combinations)
```

I concede that this approach means a lot of unnecessary combinations due to repeats, however I cannot even implement this so beggars can not be choosers.

Please can someone advise me on how I can either a) implement my approach or b) achieve this goal in a much more elegant way.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if any clarification needs to be made, this was tough to explain.

Comment: can you provide some sample `data` and `combinations` for people to play around with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate all combinations of *k* elements drawn without replacement from a set of size *n* you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), e.g.:

```
idx = np.vstack(itertools.combinations(range(n), k)) # an (n, k) array of indices
```

For the special case where *k=2* it's often faster to use the indices of the upper triangle of an *n x n* matrix, e.g.:

```
idx = np.vstack(np.triu_indices(n, 1)).T
```